# What is the best way to organize the folders and files in my web project?

Tags: design, architecture, web-development

I've been doing technical studies in web design for a while. I have developed several web pages, however, I have not published any.

This year I plan to publish my first website. I would like to know how should I order the folders and their various files (index.html, scss, js, multimedia, child web pages) in the best and most optimized way.

Also, I would like you to give me some recommendations on the structure of folders and/or other topics.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a too vague question to answer :) In general, depending on your project type, it is a good idea to start with a sample application template and check its default structure. E.g. ASP.NET MVC5 or ASP.NET Core MVC/Razor have their own recommended folder structure you can build on and adjust as per your needs **if** any such need occurs. Depending on what particular web project it is (what framework, language, etc), you can search for best practices for that particular type. Of course, there are some general ideas about separation of concerns, like not mixing various types of logic (presentation, business, etc), but there are many resources dealing with those general principles online.